# What options if any are there to upload a file to a server without triggering the user's firewall?

Tags: c++, winapi, file-upload, ftp, wininet

I'd like my beta application to upload logs to a server and/or email them to me. Part of the reason is that the target users are frequently non-technical, and this also raises the issue of my application triggering a Firewall "do you want to allow this" popup.

Of course everyone has firewalls configured differently but are there techniques I can use which will be very unlikely to be blocked?

I would prefer to use something very simple like [WinINet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385331%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to upload the file directly to a server directory so I don't have to write a server application... is FTP a viable option here or is FTP typically blocked?

Comment: Can you just upload via an HTTP `POST` to a webserver? That traffic is far less likely to be blocked/dropped than outbound FTP traffic.

Comment: @admdrew this would require some sort of server coding? Or can something so simple be provided by a typical webserver "for free"?

Comment: Yes, you'd need to build the logic yourself, but there are definitely resources out there to help you do that easily.

Comment: Using HTTP POST (and telling users how to allow the firewall exception if necessary) is probably your best bet. Doing anything tricky to try to avoid the firewall popup is likely to get you flagged as malware by A/V.

Comment: Is it a reasonable idea to use curl i.e. my application ships with and spawns curl.exe, rather than linking libcurl into my binary?

Comment: @John: No, because that will cause the popup to effectively read "<some program that I didn't buy> tries to access the Internet". Your customers won't expect to see Curl.EXE in that message. But if you linked in libcurl, the popup will now read "<new app I just installed> tries to access the Internet", which is a lot less scary.